# ABBYY Cloud OCR

Tags: php, html, ocr, abbyy, abbyy-cloud-ocr

Using the php sample that ABBYY provides http://pastebin.com/SeN8mdya I've been able to convert an image to text. Works like a charm. Now I'm trying to use an web interface to take a picture on a mobile device and send that to the ABBYY ocr service and return the resulting text. My code that takes the picture:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Camera access on mobile web!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:0;
                width:200px;
            }
            div.message {
                background-color:green;
                border-radius:4px;
                color:white;
                display:none;
                padding:5px 0;
                text-align:center;
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="logo-mobile.png" id="lunchbox-logo" />
            <div class="message"><strong>Thanks for the submission!</strong></div>
            <p>Submit your receipt straight from your web browser!!</p>


            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processImage?language=english&exportFormat=txt">
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="receipt[data]">
                <input type="button" onClick="submitReceipt();" value="Submit">    
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitReceipt(){
                var token = 'NEVER-COMMIT-TOKENS :)';
                var file = document.getElementsByName('receipt[data]')[0].files[0];

                fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('access_token', token);
                fd.append('receipt[data]', file);

                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open('POST', 'http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processImage?language=english&exportFormat=txt');
                req.send(fd);

                document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].style.display = "block";

            }  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both work independently of each other. I'd like the camera page to submit the picture to ABBYY and wait for the returning result and then display it. All my attempts have broken it. Thanks again.

Comment: If anyone wants to test it the password for the cloud ocr is pTcQRiQ2FQE3TNxD6+JkaKsE. There isn't many credits in the account but I didn't want to post it to pastebin. Thanks.

Comment: OT: Just wanted to give some props to this project. This could be helpful to people with disabilities.

Answer (score 1):

What you're ending up inadvertently doing here is submitting the filename of the uploaded file, rather than the file content. There are fancy ways to get the content of the file nowadays, but it'll be much simpler to just skip all the fancy AJAX stuff you're doing, remove the `onClick` handler, and submit the form normally.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

Comment: Remove the `onClick` handler and the associated JavaScript. The form should function correctly without them.